# Navigation Bar removed

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

[image]I have used navigation item in my app. In the log out method I have popped to root view controller i.e. my loginViewController but while doing so the navigation bar gets removed. I have tried putting the code to load in viewWillAppear but it is still not working. Could you please help me?

Here is my code for log out:

```
@IBAction func btnLogOutClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        let log : LoginViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
        let window:UIWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
        let navControl : UINavigationController = window.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
        if (!(navControl .isEqual(log)))
        {
            window.rootViewController = log
        }
        navControl.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    }
```

My viewWillAppear-

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        self.navigationItem.title = "Select Client"
        // create a new butto
        let button: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom)
        //set image for button
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "logo-icon"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        //set frame
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 30)
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
        //assign button to navigationbar
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton


    }
```

Here is my storyboard-

I am using pushViewController to reach to tab bar controller from login view controller

Comment: Add `super.viewWillAppear(animated)` as the first line of code in your `viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)`  method

Comment: And also use `self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)` instead of `self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried to add it but it isn't working yet. When I put a debug point and do "po self.navigationController" it prints "nil".

Comment: @Amit navControl.rootViewController = log is syntactically wrong. As it is a get only property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code to change the `NavigationController` stack :

```
let oldVCs = self.navigationController?.viewControllers
let newVCs = [UIViewController]()

 // Add your root VC in new array of VCs
 newVCs.append(oldVCs![0])
 // Add your new VC just after your root VC
 let log : LoginViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController

 newVCs.append(log)

 self.navigationController?.setViewControllers(newVCs , animated: true)
```

In this the animation will be like pushing a new controller in stack.

If you want to completely leave that stack and create a new one:

```
let log : LoginViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController

let loginNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: log)            
self.view.window?.rootViewController = loginNavigationController
```

Comment: This works, thank you. But it adds tab bar at the bottom of login screen from previous screen.

I am using a Tab bar controller to display different tabs, while doing log out from on of the tab, the tab bar is still visible on the login scree.

Comment: In that case your root view is Tab bar controller I guess

Comment: I have attached storyboard in post now

Comment: Thank you so much. It works as needed.
One question though, why the root view was tab bar controller instead of login View controller?

Comment: your window root view controller is tab bar and on that you have added navigation controller stack.